# Firebase pagination in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i'm using Firebase firestore for an app i'm working on. Basically, i have a **Collection('Chat')** that may contain **thousand of documents** i need a way to implement **firebase pagination** to limit how much document is retrieved from the backend.

im using **streamBuilder** and passing the **Query** below as stream :

```
stream: widget.messageDocRef
      .collection('Chat').orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
      .limit(80)
      .snapshots();
```

i have a **ListView** and a **scrollController** for it, code:

```
ListView(
        physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        reverse: true,
        controller: _scrollController,
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 10.0),
        children: messagesBubble,
      ),
```

i couldn't find any good documentation on how to implement it in flutter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a `ScrollController`, then inside the `initState` do the following :

```
@override
  void initState() {
    this.getdbData();
    super.initState();
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels ==
          _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        getdbData();
      }
    });
  }
```

So first add a listener that will register a closure to be called when the object changes. Then check if `position.pixel` is equal to the `position.maxScrollExtent` and call the method if the above is satisfied.

Also don't forget to dispose the controller:

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollPosition-class.html

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollController-class.html

The `getdbData()` is the method that will retrieve the data from the database which you will assign to the property `stream`

Comment: I know how to do that, i don't know how to use [Firebase pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) ,in their documentation they talk about **Paginate a query** where they have multiple query!!.

Comment: All they are doing is multiple query.. They didn't do any pagination https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#paginate_a_query.. You can do multiple query in the method `getDbData` use `await` in the first query and assign the query to a variable then use that variable in the next query..